# hostip.info API response data extraction

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently trying to extract the values of following API call:
http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.19&position=true

The result should maybe be an array like:

```
$my = array(
    'country_name' => 'UNITED STATES',
    'country_iso' => 'US',
    'city_name' => 'Sugar Grove, IL',
    'latitude' => 41.7696,
    'longitude' => -88.4588
);
```

Anyone has a clever regexp to make this happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They seem to have a `get_xml.php` which would be much easier to parse, but it's not in the docs. Maybe ask whether that one is official and parse that using simpleXML

Comment: true but i had trouble parsing it I think i'm gonna open another question. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$response = file('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.19&position=true');
foreach ($response as $line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    if (!empty($line)) {
        $parts = explode(': ', $line);
        $array[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Country] => UNITED STATES (US)
    [City] => Sugar Grove, IL
    [Latitude] => 41.7696
    [Longitude] => -88.4588
    [IP] => 12.215.42.19
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Country: (.*?) \((.*?)\)\nCity: ([^\n]*)\n\nLatitude: ([-0-9.]*)\nLongitude: ([-0-9.]*)\n`

But better use many regex's:

```
Country: (.*?) \(([^\n]*)\)
City: ([^\n]*)
Latitude: ([-0-9.]*)
Longitude: ([-0-9.]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet.

@Dan Grossman - my 2 cents: add `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` and/or `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flags to the file() function, so you won't need to check for empty lines.

I'd go with the non-regexp version.